# dwm window manager on VmWare Player - no copy-paste between host and guest

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, clipboard, clipboard-manager

I run ubuntu on VMWare Player on windows and I have my custom [dwm window manager](https://github.com/ChoppinBlockParty/Yuki-s-dwm). Using GPaste as a clipboard manager. The clipboard copy-paste is not working between guest and host, when I switch to the Gnome window manager it works. What can I miss that causes the copy-paste not to work? It worked when I run the same setup on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `/etc/xdg/autostart/vmware-user.desktop` that executes `/usr/bin/vmware-user`. My custom UI does not follow Open Desktop specification so it does not do that. Added this command to my start-up file and all is great. VirtualBox works much worse than VMWare, ironically, clipboard there worked out-of-box with my custom window manager.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
cat .xinitrc
/usr/bin/vmware-user-suid-wrapper &
exec dwm
```